# How to center button in TeachingBubble FluentUI component?

Tags: fluent-ui, office-fabric, fluentui-react

I'm using Fluent UI's [TeachingBubble](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/teachingbubble)  component. I want it to have one button, which should be centered. How can that be done? I'm unable to move it from the bottom right corner.

Current code:

```
      <TeachingBubble
        headline="Welcome"
        primaryButtonProps={{
          children: "Next",
          onClick: () => alert("Primary button pressed!"),
        }}
      >
        This is some content.
      </TeachingBubble>
```

This outputs:

[image]

What should be added to this code so that the primary button is centered (at the red cross I marked)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button is inside footer part of TeachingBubble, so the style of footer should be changed:

```
<TeachingBubble
        headline="Welcome"
        primaryButtonProps={{
          children: "Next",
          onClick: () => alert("Primary button pressed!"),
        }}
        styles={{
          footer: {
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
          },
        }}
      >
        Some text
      </TeachingBubble>
```

That renders as:

[image]

Comment: This should be marked as the best answer. I verified the code example centers the button.